# DataMax and DataMin Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I created the measure to filter the ventures that have sales in all months within the selected period using the filter, and to return only the quantity of sales for the last month. I need this value to be repeated in all other months:

```
VisualQuantitySales = 
VAR Datemin = CALCULATE(MIN(d_Calendario[DataBase]), ALLSELECTED(d_Calendario))
VAR Datemax = CALCULATE(MAX(d_Calendario[DataBase]), ALLSELECTED(d_Calendario))
VAR QuantitySelectedMonths = DATEDIFF(Datamin, Datamax, MONTH) + 1
var emp = CALCULATE(MAX(f_Management_Sales[IdEmpreendimento]))
var table = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUMX(
            SUMMARIZE(
                f_Management_Sales,
                f_Management_Sales[IdEmpreendimento],
                f_Management_Sales[EMPREENDIMENTO],
                d_Calendario[DataBase],
                "MesesSelecionados", QuantitySelectedMonths,
                "QtdVendasEmpreendimento", COUNT(f_Management_Sales[IdEmpreendimento]),
                "QtdMesesComVenda", 
                CALCULATE(
                    COUNTX(
                        FILTER(
                            SUMMARIZE(
                                f_Management_Sales, 
                                f_Management_Sales[IdEmpreendimento],
                                d_Calendario[DataBase]
                            ),
                            [DataBase] >= Datamin && [DataBase] <= Datamax
                        ),
                        [DataBase]
                    ),
                    f_Management_Sales[IdEmpreendimento] = SELECTEDVALUE(f_Management_Sales[IdEmpreendimento]),
                    ALL(d_Calendario),
                    ALL(f_Management_Sales)
                )
            ),
            IF(        
                [QtdMesesComVenda] = [MesesSelecionados] && 
                [DataBase] >= Datamin && [DataBase] <= Datamax, [QtdVendasEmpreendimento]
            )
        ),
        d_Calendario[DataBase] = Datamax,
        ALL(d_Calendario)
    )

RETURN 
    table
```

The measure returns the correct values, but when I apply it in another measure, the formula doesn't work. I want to apply it in this measure:

`
VisualVGVMesmoMix =
SUMX(
SUMMARIZE(
f_Management_Sales,
d_cfr_Empreendimento[Id_Empreendimento],
d_Calendario[DataBase]
),
[VisualQuantitySales] * [VisualTeste]
)

`

The value returned is not correct; it seems to ignore all the filters I applied in the previous measure.
Now, if I change two variables of the measure VisualQtdVendadUltimoMesMesmoMixTeste like this:

`VAR Datamin = DATE(2023,01,01) VAR Datamax = DATE(2023,07,01)`

It returns exactly the values I am looking for. But this cannot be applied because I need the date filter to be respected.

The value returned is not correct; it seems to ignore all the filters I applied in the previous measure.
Now, if I change two variables of the measure VisualQtdVendadUltimoMesMesmoMixTeste like this:

`VAR Datamin = DATE(2023,01,01)

VAR Datamax = DATE(2023,07,01)`

It returns exactly the values I am looking for. But this cannot be applied because I need the date filter to be respected.